# what steps do I need to take to set up a scheduled trigger that sends data on a weekly basis?

Tags: node.js, jira, jira-rest-api, forge

I'm new to Forge and I'm trying to figure out how to use scheduledTrigger. My goal is to send data from my Forge app to my Node.js server every week. Specifically, I want to retrieve worklogs data and send it to the server once a week on Mondays.

I have a React front-end that calls a Node.js back-end function using invoke(), and it successfully retrieves the data I need. However, I'm not sure how to set up the 'scheduledTrigger' to make this happen automatically every week.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to use  'scheduledTrigger' in this context? Any sample code or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

i already have created NodeJS server that receive data from my forge application but i want my jira application to send it weekly

Comment: you can use the scheduledTrigger function provided by Forge

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how to define scheduledTrigger: https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/forge/add-scheduled-trigger/

I would set interval to daily or hourly and persist last execution date-time via [Storage API](https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/forge/runtime-reference/storage-api/). If last execution date-time was executed week ago then perform desired action and update last execution date-time to now.